# BAW with deterministic rate, dividend and volatility term structures

Tags: american-options

Is anyone aware of a paper or B.Sc/M.Sc. thesis that derives the Barone-Adesi-Whaley approximation for American options with deterministic rate, dividend and volatility term structures? I have googled but without much luck as yet.

I may be able to derive this myself, but if the work has been done before then that is easier of course.

Comment: Hey:) Have you found an answer to your question in the mean time? I started to ask myself the same question recently. Dividend yield and volatility play such a passive role in the derivation that I doubt something breaks when they vary deterministically over time?

Comment: @Kevin Nope haven't found an answer yet. I have not really looked at the problem much lately actually. The reason I wanted to look at deterministic vol term structure is to try to generalise that to stoch vol via Hull White formula.

Comment: @Kevin Happy to talk about this more using other channels. Not sure btw if dividends really play a passive role: without dividends and American call would be worth as much as an European call.

Comment: Hi Frido, thank you! Let me send you a direct text. But you caught me with the dividend yield and the call option. I was (by default) thinking about an American put option with positive interest rates.